# Valgrind error - cannot execute binary file

Tags: c++, macos, unix, gcc, valgrind

For some reason I can't make **valgrind** work with my **Cocoa** apllication on **OS X 10.6**, compiled with **Apple GCC 4.2.1**... After googling this error I found out that **valgrind** doesn't work with 64-bit executables, however my application and all the frameworks it uses is being compiled with the **-m32** flag and **file** commmand says **./MyAppName: Mach-O executable i386**, **Kernel** is also **i386**.

Can somebody please tell me why won't **valgrind** work then?

By the way, I got **valgrind** from **MacPorts**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded latest **valgrind v3.6.1** from **valgrind.org** and compiled it under OS X and it works without any issue.

Answer (score 5):

Just a note that I had the same problem, but reinstalling with the `+universal` port option, as in

```
sudo port install valgrind +universal
```

made the MacPorts version work for me.

Answer (score 4):

I am using the [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) build of valgrind and it works for me. After downloading valgrind it applies some patches, afaik the one discussed [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=267997). Additionally, it uses the flags `--enable-only64bit --build=amd64-darwin` when compiling on 64-bit darwin.

For me also neither the macports build worked, nor did the build that i created my self from the vanilla tar.gz file from the valgrind page. It seems that the provided autoconf script does not support newer macs running in 64-bit mode.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Barbaz! However, after installing Homebrew build valgrind still doesn't work... Should I specify some additional flags and not just brew install valgrind?

Comment: brew install valgrind should just work. Can you execute valgrind? Like valgrind --help for example? This already lead to a segfault for me with the macports + vanilla version.

Comment: I had no problems running MacPorts or Homebrew valgrind --help... And I uninstalled MacPorts version before installing Homebrew version.

Comment: Then you are experiencing another problem. Can you be more specific about "can't make valgrind work"?

Comment: Valgrind works by itself, but when I try to analyze my application running valgrind ./MyAppName, it always reports error './MyAppName: cannot execute binary file'. If I try to execute ./MyAppName.app, the error would be the same, only path would differ...